# the same code doesn't work when I put into jstl tag

Tags: jstl

When I do like this

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${book.display}">
         <eb:glyphicon-status icon="eye-open" value="${book.id}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <eb:glyphicon-status icon="eye-close" value="${book.id}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

It works fine.
But when I create tag `showeye`

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="eb"%>
<%@ attribute name="isDisplay" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" %>
<%@ attribute name="bookId" required="true" rtexprvalue="true" type="java.lang.Long" %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isDisplay}">
        <eb:glyphicon-status icon="eye-open" value="${bookId}" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <eb:glyphicon-status icon="eye-close" value="${bookId}" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And when I put it on the page

```
<eb:showeye isDisplay="${book.display}" bookId="${book.id}" />
```

The condition does not work properly. I always got false result.
What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean? This is the code of `showeye.tag`. It's in the same folder as any other tag I use on my page

Comment: What happens if you put in `isDisplay="${true}"` rather than passing `${book.display}`?

Comment: it returns result for `true` values

Comment: So then your problem is with `book.display`, which is either false or `null`, etc.

Comment: But why it's as a parameter of the tag it seems to be `null`(because it returns always `false` result but I've got `true` and `false` `display` values - that does mean that the `true` statement never  happen)? What is incorrect?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from your answer to my comment above, I understood that if you entered `<eb:showeye isDisplay="${true}" bookId="${book.id}" />`, you hit the expected branch of your `c:choose` statement & got `<eb:glyphicon-status icon="eye-open" value="${bookId}" />` outputted. Is that happening? If so, your problem isn't with your tag, it's with your inputs to the tag.

Comment: You are right - it's hit expected branch. But I don't understand what is the problem with input

Comment: Well if you've ruled out a problem with the tag, it looks like at issue with `book.display` — have you debugged its value at this point?